# Why do I get the answer 1 only to program to find divisor?

Tags: python, function, variables, input, output

This is the program to find divisor of two numbers but the answer of any number I input comes out to be 1. Where am I going wrong?

```
def divisor(a,b):
    result=1
    for i in range(b,-1):
        if a%i==0 and b%i==0:
            result=i
            break

    return result

num=input("calculate HCF of: ").split(",")
print(divisor(int(num[0]),int(num[1])))
```

Comment: Cannot duplicate.  When I run this code with an input of `6,9`, I get output of `3`.

Comment: It doesn't have a problem, maybe there is a problem with the test value you entered, you can try `28, 8`.

Comment: not sure, probably you are getting string after splitting the input. convert them to a number then check again. Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: This is an inefficient way to compute the value in the first place. Use [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) instead.

Comment: It would be better to start the for loop at the smaller of a and b, instead of always using b.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1, min(a, b)+1):
    result = 0
    if a%i==b%i==0:
        result+=1
```